# pandas ewma function with nan values

Tags: pandas

I am able to reproduce pandas' ewma function for a series without nan values, but I am confused on how ewma works with nan values in between.

For example, for a series: `[nan,2,nan,4,5]`, ewma with a center of mass 25 gives: `[nan, 2, 2, 3.0392006149116,3.72707131594179]`.

I can see if there is a nan value, then it will just forward fill. But for the number after the nan value (4 in this case), I am not sure how the ewma gives 3.0392?

It doesn't seem to be applying ewma on [2,4] or [2,2,4]. Can someone show me how it's calculated? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's an unexpected behaviour of `adjust` parameter in `pd.ewma()`. You can set it to `False` to make the standard Exponential Moving Average formula work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([np.nan, 2, np.nan, 4, 5])

ema = pd.ewma(s, com=25, adjust=False)

# formula
# EMA_t = alpha*S_t + (1-alpha)*EMA_{t-1}
alpha = 1/(1+25)
ema[4] == alpha*s[4] + (1-alpha)*ema[3]

Out[64]: True
```